# Python server can't access file if there is a blank space in the path

Tags: python-2.7

I have a server that streams mp3 files. It works fine, however, if the file has any space in the path name, it says "file not found".

I've tried putting %20 instead of the blank space but no success (in fact, it does it automatically, when it prints the request.path, all the blank spaces are converted to %20 on the console).

I'm using the Twisted Matrix library. This is the code I'm using:

```
class playMP3(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        this=urlparse.urlparse(request.path)#scheme,netloc,path,query
        root,ext=os.path.splitext(this.path)
        filename=os.path.basename(request.path)
        fileFolder=request.path.replace(filename,"")
        self.serverRoot=os.getcwd()
        print (request.path)
        if ext==".mp3":
            thisFile=File(self.serverRoot+request.path)
            return File.render_GET(thisFile,request)

resource = playMP3()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. All I had to do was `request.path = request.path.replace('%20', ' ')`